# geometry data type of snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geospatial, geometry-surface

I am trying to use the geometry data type and was wondering what the unit of the spatial functions will be. The documentation says as below. Is there a way I can pass a unit to the function. If not, how do i find out the unit

> The measurement functions (e.g. ST_LENGTH) use the same units as the
> coordinate system

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_length.html#returns

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the link also does not speak about the unit and the conversion mechanism. How do I know which unit is output by the function. Do i need to go to each SRS specification and find out?

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised by the results, and the docs could be clearer.

With a `geography`, `st_length()` returns the distance in meters, as described in the docs. For example, for a line between SF and a point 10km to the east:

```sql
select st_length(
  to_geography('LINESTRING(-122.4194 37.7749,-122.3094 37.7749 )')
);
-- 9,668.032993573
```

[image]

However, that's not what you get when you have a `geometry` between the same points:

```sql
select st_length(
  to_geometry('LINESTRING(-122.4194 37.7749,-122.3094 37.7749 )')
);
-- 0.11
```

So where does the 0.11 come from? Vertica says:

> "For GEOMETRY objects, the length is measured in Cartesian coordinate units. For GEOGRAPHY objects, the length is measured in meters."

Same on PostGIS:

> For geometry types: returns the 2D Cartesian length of the geometry [...]
>
> For geography types: [...] Units of length are in meters. [...]
>
> https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html

I'll notify our docs team so we make the necessary update on https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_length.html#returns.